# What is the theory behind the Navigational Style in Alloy

Tags: alloy

In the Alloy well-know [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262017156) by Daniel Jakson he writes about three different styles in specifying constraints in Alloy: 1) predicate calculus **2) navigational style**, and 3) relational calculus.  (Section 3.1, page 34)

The theory behind the first and the last ones are somehow clear to to me as the first is the conventional first order logic when we take relations as predicates; and the last is relational calculus in which everything is taken as a relation and constraints are specified by employing the equation symbol and some algebraic operations (without quantifiers). In the book, it is said that **the second one has the most expressive power** (page 35).

**My Question:**
What is the theory behind the second one (i.e., navigational style)? Where should I look for (and under which terminology) to gain more information regarding this one in theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motivation for the navigational style is that you want something between predicate calculus, which has no operations on sets or relations, so is very awkward and verbose to use in practice (and also less expressive due to the lack of transitive closure), and relational calculus, as pioneered by Tarski, which gives you relational operators but has no quantifiers, which is quite unnatural for most people (but which allows some beautifully succinct ways to express properties). The navigational style comes between the two, and gives you both set/relation operators and quantifiers, so in this sense -- informally at least, and probably formally too if you defined the three sublanguages carefully -- it's more expressive than either. At the same time, I had in mind that most people are comfortable with simple first order quantifiers but aren't so comfortable with relational join, and tend therefore to write formulas in which expressions denote sets. You can think of each of these expressions as starting at some atom, denoted by a quantified variable, and then "navigating" along relations to get larger and larger expressions that denote sets of atoms. This is how I think of an expression like me.parents.children : you start with me, navigate to my parents, then from them to their children -- and the result is the set containing me and my siblings. In my experience, this navigational style is what most people gravitate naturally towards.

It's true that if you had to pick one style of the three that matched OCL, it would be this navigational style, although it's true that OCL has a very much more complex semantics (due to various coercions and flattenings that happen automatically at each step), where in Alloy the semantics is just standard sets and relations. The syntax is probably more influenced by object oriented languages like Java, even though they don't have the kind of relational image that Alloy has (that is, if you have a field f and can write x.f, you can't write xs.f for the set of all objects that are mapped to by f from the objects in the set xs!). Note however that there is no special syntax here; these are just styles of usage of the same operators.

When I wrote this page in the book, I thought it would give readers some useful intuitions, but it seems to have just caused more confusion!

Answer (score 2):

In Appendix E - Alternative Approaches, Daniel Jackson discusses OCL,  which has a navigational style. I would assume he borrowed the syntax from it, as he discusses it as related work that precedes Alloy.

Comment: This make it more difficult for me to study it, as OCL seems to have a complex underlying theoretical semantic ( if I assume there is one).